# How to display an enum property with icon_only=True and use the full width of a row?

Tags: scripting, interface, properties

I wanted to ask how I can make an enum property use the full width of a row if I only want to display the icons.

Here my code:

```
row = layout.row()
row.prop(parts[0].render_options[0], "render_option", expand=True, icon_only=True)
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

How can I make this use the full width of the row?
So it will be displayed like this (but only with the icon in the center and no text):

[image]